# how do i make jquery mobile password check UI

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a page that checking password with JQM 1.4.

And you can see the design on the url below.

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c19ea08

How do make each key numeric button ?

Is there any examples or references ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use simple numeric input (not 4 of them). When the input has focus, native OS-specific numeric keyboard appears.